How to show the specific item to indicator position in spin wheel roll method

I want to show the given index item after rotate animation at top center where the indicator was located .
this is the method to get the result but its still show wrong item. Here is my component written in vue.js application. Help me to fix this problem.
``
roll(index, list, duration = 4000) {
            // Step 1: Find the item in the list by index and log it
            const item = list[index];
            console.log("Index:", index);
            console.log("Item:", item);

            // Step 2: Calculate the degree of the segment that the item occupies
            const segmentDegree = 360 / list.length; // Degree per segment
            const itemSegmentDegree = segmentDegree * index;
            console.log("Segment Degree of Item:", itemSegmentDegree);

            // Step 3: Calculate the top center segment degree
            const topCenterSegmentDegree = 0; // Top center is assumed to be 0 degrees

            // Step 4: Calculate the rotation needed
            // To have the item at the top center, adjust by subtracting itemSegmentDegree from 360
            const totalDegrees = 360 * 6; // Number of full rotations
            const rotationToAlignItemAtTop = (360 - itemSegmentDegree) % 360;
            const newEndDegree = totalDegrees + rotationToAlignItemAtTop;

            console.log(
                "Rotation to Align Item at Top:",
                rotationToAlignItemAtTop
            );
            console.log("New End Degree:", newEndDegree);

            // Get the wheel element
            const wheel = this.$refs.wheel;
            if (!wheel) {
                console.error("Wheel element is not available.");
                return;
            }

            // Reset previousEndDegree for a new spin
            this.previousEndDegree = this.previousEndDegree % 360;

            // Cancel any previous animation
            if (this.animation) {
                this.animation.cancel();
            }

            // Perform the animation
            this.animation = wheel.animate(
                [
                    { transform: `rotate(${this.previousEndDegree}deg)` },
                    { transform: `rotate(${newEndDegree}deg)` }
                ],
                {
                    duration: duration, // Use the provided duration
                    direction: "normal",
                    easing: "cubic-bezier(0.440, -0.205, 0.000, 1.130)", // Use a smooth easing function
                    fill: "forwards",
                    iterations: 1
                }
            );

            // Update the rolling state and handle the reward box
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.rolling = false;
                console.log("done rolling");
                this.rewardBox = true;
            }, duration);

            // Update previousEndDegree to the new end degree
            this.previousEndDegree = newEndDegree;
        },
``

How I suppose to change the method which part is wrong

What does the current code currently do? is it always incorrect by the same degree? Can you show a true example of the console.log outputs

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
